# Entity Framework 6: Data Manipulation

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to EF and I've only worked with EF 6. When I use it to access the data from a database that I have already designed I don't see any method that allows me to manipulate data. To solve this temporarily I created some stored procedures for adding, deleting and updating data. 
I would like to know if what I am doing is the right way to manipulate data in EF or not. In case it is not the right way how can I do this using the built in features of EF6. MSDN said there is an add object but couldn't find it.

Comment: While you can certainly use stored procs to perform CRUD operations and use EF with these, it kind of defeats the purpose of using an OR/M to perform data access if that's the direction you go. Can you please give a little more information about your database itself and which workflow you're using with EF6 (e.g. SQL Server with Code First or Model First).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been some changes in the API. EF6 does not use ObjectContext anymore, it uses a DbContext. This can be generated from a Database Model, or created using a Model first approach.

Old syntax:

```
objectContext.AddToUsers(user);
```

is now:

```
dbContext.Users.Add(user);
```

Here are some basic samples:

insert:

```
using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
     var user = new User { ID=1, Name="Test" };
     dbContext.Users.Add(user); // Add user
     dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Save changes to DB
}
```

update:

```
using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
     var user = dbContext.Users.Find(1);// find by ID = 1
     user.Name = "New Name"; // Change name
     dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Save changes to DB

}
```

delete:

```
using(var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
     var user = dbContext.Users.Find(1);// find by ID = 1
     dbContext.Users.Remove(user); // delete user
     dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Save changes to DB
}
```

So, no need for stored procedures.. definetly not needed for simple CRUD.